# Display not updating on the QTimer?

Tags: qt, qtimer

Trying to display text based on when the QTimer fires off...

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_label1 = new QLabel("My Label not working", this);

    QTimer* timerDisplay = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timerDisplay, SIGNAL(Started()), this, SLOT(updateDisplay(this)));
    timerDisplay->start(10);

}


void updateDisplay(MainWindow* m_this)
{
    QString out;
    out = "hello";

    m_this->m_label1->setText("asdf");
}
```

Comment: In addition to what peppe has answered, `QTimer` does not have a `Started()` signal, and not even a `started()` signal. The only signal provided by a `QTimer` is `timeout()`, + those inherited by `QObject`.

Answer (score 3):

```
connect(timerDisplay, SIGNAL(Started()), this, SLOT(updateDisplay(this)));
```

This statement is failing. And you're ignoring the message that Qt is printing on your console.

The problem is, you can't pass variables in `connect` statements like that. And what for, by the way? You can use `this` in the `updateDisplay` method without the need of passing it in explicitely!

Comment: Two things I forgot:  1)putting the declaration in a slot in the header file, 2)it should be void MainWindow::updateDisplay().

Comment: Also, it's worth adding that in this context, [QObject::sender()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) is how you'd get the.. well, sender.  Just call it in the updateDisplay() slot and break in the debugger and it'll be a delightful surprise.